# Add check box to datalist dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I have a datalist display the reportname. I am binding data to datalist in page load event. How can I add a check box dynamically next to `reportName` if the level is `Admin`

```
<asp:datalist  id="datalistRpt"  runat="server" CellSpacing="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ShowHeader="True" RepeatColumns="2">   
    <ItemTemplate>                      
        <a href="(<%# Eval("REPORT_ID")%>,'<%# Eval("REPORT_NAME")%>')"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "REPORT_NAME_N") %></a>                
    </ItemTemplate>                
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "User_level") %>                       
    </ItemTemplate>                
</asp:datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the check box and then just change its visibility based on the level.

In the .aspx file add:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyBox" runat="server" />
```

In your page_load event add something like:

```
If (User_Level = Admin) Then
    chkMyBox.Visible = True
Else
    chkMyBox.Visible = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it in markup and set the visibility true or false:

```
<ItemTemplate>                      
    <a href="(<%# Eval("REPORT_ID")%>,'<%# Eval("REPORT_NAME")%>')"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "REPORT_NAME_N") %></a> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdmin"  Checked="false" Visible='<%# Eval("User_level").ToString() == "Admin"? true:false %>' runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>              
</ItemTemplate>
```